# Delete Prices conditional on Date

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have a dataframe shape 3000 x 120. Each column represents daily stock prices for a ticker. The 2nd row of each column represents the date that stock was sold or expected to be sold. 
 (e.g)

```
               AAPL         GOOGLE         IBM
**Sell date.  2017/APRIL/01.  2021/FEB/03.   2015/MAR/3**

2019/jan/02  5             4              3
2019/jan/03. 4             4              4
2019/jan/04. 4             4              5
2019/jan/05  3             5              2 
2012/Mar/03  10            20             22
```

As you can see, the df contains prices for stocks after the sell date of the stock- i want to remove ( or replace with 0 value) price data that appear after the sell date, while preserving the frame. Given the size of df, would rather NOT do this manually!

This is what I've tried so far but getting an error " ValueError: Lengths must match"

```
var = dftest2.columns

x = int
for v in var:
    if dftest2.index <= dftest2.iloc[0]:
        x = x       
    else:
        0
```

**This is what the df should look like**

```
               AAPL         GOOGLE         IBM
**Sell date.  2017/APRIL/01.  2021/FEB/03.   2015/MAR/3**

2019/jan/02  0             4              0
2019/jan/03. 0             4              0
2019/jan/04. 0             4              0
2019/jan/05  0             5              0 
..........
..........
2012/Mar/03  10            20             22
```

Comment: So in your above example, the second column should become 0 because Feb 3rd 2021 is > the sell date (which is the index) for every row?

Comment: Exactly @ ALollz. Bear in mind that the index goes all the way to 2010, therefore will need to preserve the price data prior to sell date (2017/APRIL/01)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood your concern, but let me try to help.
First of all be sure that your dates are formatted as a datetime.date or datetime.datetime (a.k.a. dt.date or dt.datetime). This is required for comparing it to another date.

Run the following code and see if this is something you are looking for:

```
# Dataframe Example
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Test': [dt.date(2016,1,1),1,2,3],
    'Test2': [dt.date(2017,1,3),0,2,4],
    'Test3': [dt.date(2029,4,22),1,2,3],
    'Test4': [dt.date(2034,3,1),0,2,4]}
    )

df.index =  [dt.date(2019,1,1),dt.date(2019,1,2),dt.date(2019,1,3),dt.date(2019,1,4)]

display(df)

# Delete Column Test3 and Test4, because the dates in df.Test3[0] and df.Test4[0] are in the future

for i in df:
    if df[i][0] > dt.date.today():
        df = df.drop(columns=i)

display(df)
```

Output:

```
    Test    Test2   Test3   Test4
2019-01-01  2016-01-01  2017-01-03  2029-04-22  2034-03-01
2019-01-02  1   0   1   0
2019-01-03  2   2   2   2
2019-01-04  3   4   3   4


Test    Test2
2019-01-01  2016-01-01  2017-01-03
2019-01-02  1   0
2019-01-03  2   2
2019-01-04  3   4
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Not quiet . I need to preserve the columns given that the time series starts in 2010 and therefore want to preserve the prices of the tickers  prior to sell date. 
What is required is that values ( after sell date) are removed, or replaced with 0 or nan's. 
The columns however should remain in tact. So for your columns all columns should be in the final DF, however those prices which appear on the df after the specified sell date need to removed or replaced with 0.
Hope that clarifies it?

Comment: Updated the OP to display what the df should look like after processing....hope it helps

Comment: I have submitted a new answer. Try it out and let me know if it helped you or not. :)

Comment: Thanks again. Tried running your new code however got an error "TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'datetime.date'" As you suspected my ''Sell date'' row is not propoerly formatted as when I converted the original input data i used dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') to align the data with the index. Is there another way to do convert this to dt.datetime format as im search the net but have yet to find something... i imagine its quiet easy!

Answer (score 0):

If your dates are formatted correctly this code should help you out:

```
# Dataframe Example
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Test': [dt.date(2016,1,1),1,2,3],
    'Test2': [dt.date(2017,1,3),1,2,4],
    'Test3': [dt.date(2029,4,22),1,2,3],
    'Test4': [dt.date(2034,3,1),1,2,4]}
    )

df.index =  [dt.date(2019,1,1),dt.date(2019,1,2),dt.date(2019,1,3),dt.date(2019,1,4)]

display(df)


for i in df:
    for j in arange(1, len(df)):
        if df[i][0] < df.index[j]:
            df[i][j] = 0

display(df)
```

Output:

```
        Test    Test2   Test3   Test4
2019-01-01  2016-01-01  2017-01-03  2029-04-22  2034-03-01
2019-01-02  1   1   1   1
2019-01-03  2   2   2   2
2019-01-04  3   4   3   4


Test    Test2   Test3   Test4
2019-01-01  2016-01-01  2017-01-03  2029-04-22  2034-03-01
2019-01-02  0   0   1   1
2019-01-03  0   0   2   2
2019-01-04  0   0   3   4
```

If not, here is an example of how to do convert the strings correctly:

```
# Dataframe Example
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Test': ['2016/JAN/2',1,6],
     'Test2': ['2017/APR/19',2,5],
     'Test3': ['2029/MAY/03', 3,4]
    })

df.index =  ['Sell Date',dt.date(2019,1,1),dt.date(2019,1,2)]

display(df)

months = pd.DataFrame({'Month': ['JAN','FEB','MAR','APR','MAY','JUN','JUL','AUG','SEP','OCT','NOV','DEC']})

newdf = pd.DataFrame(df)

for i in df:
    for j in range(len(months)):
        if df[i][0][5:5+3] == months.Month[j]:
            newdf[i][0] = newdf[i][0].replace(newdf[i][0][5:5+3],str(j+1))
            newdf[i][0] = datetime.datetime.strptime(newdf[i][0], "%Y/%m/%d").date()
            break

display(newdf)

# Delete Column

for i in df:
    for j in arange(1, len(newdf)):
        if newdf[i][0] < newdf.index[j]:
            newdf[i][j] = 0

display(newdf)
```

Output:

```
    Test    Test2   Test3
Sell Date   2016/JAN/2  2017/APR/19 2029/MAY/03
2019-01-01  1   2   3
2019-01-02  6   5   4
Test    Test2   Test3
Sell Date   2016-01-02  2017-04-19  2029-05-03
2019-01-01  1   2   3
2019-01-02  6   5   4
Test    Test2   Test3
Sell Date   2016-01-02  2017-04-19  2029-05-03
2019-01-01  0   0   3
2019-01-02  0   0   4
```